# How to remove a Qt WindowFlag?

Tags: qt

To set the window flags I use `setWindowFlags(/* flags */)` function.

How can I remove a **only one** window flag?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the binary negation flag ~

```
unsigned int flags = flags();
flags = flags & (~FlagEnum);
```

So, to remove a customization window hint: -

```
flags = flags & (~Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```